# Datetime Picker

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-3, datetime, bootstrap-4

Estou a usar este datetimer picker [datetimepicker](https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)
A data aparece assim:
2018 Janeiro 30 - 10:00
e eu quero que apareca assim:
2018-01-30 10:00

Dá para fazer em jquery ou e preciso alterar diretamente no codigo do datetime picker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O componente possui uma opção para formatar a data e a hora:

```
$("ID OU CLASSE DO CAMPO").datetimepicker(
   {format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii'}
);
```

Onde:

```
yyyy -> ano
  mm -> mês
  dd -> dia
  hh -> horas
  ii -> minutos
```

Você pode ver as opções completas na **[documentação do componente](https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/index.php)**.